# Index Notation, Moving Partial Derivative, Vector Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, index-notation

I've been having trouble understanding the Leibniz's rule when using index notation.

This is how far I've managed to expand the expression:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\overline{r} \times \left (\bigtriangledown \times \overline{A}  \right ) 
\\= \epsilon_{ijk}r_j\left (\bigtriangledown \times \overline{A}  \right )_k
\\= \epsilon _{ijk}r_j \epsilon _{klm}\partial_l A_m 
\\= \left (\delta_{il} \delta_{jm} -\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}  \right )r_j \partial_lA_m 
\\= r_j\partial_iA_j - r_j\partial_jA_i
\end{array}
$$

However, the solution is:
$$
=\partial_i\left (x_jA_j  \right )-\partial_j\left (x_jA_i  \right )+2A_i
$$
How come one can move the partial derivative and get a thrid term, there must be a fundamental piece of the puzzle that I don't understand and therfore I'm seeking for help.

Comment: Just as a matter of helping you improve your proofs: your first line *doesn't* equal the one following it (or any after that).  It's a vector quantity while all of the other expressions are scalar quantities.  You should have $$\left[\vec r\times (\nabla \times \vec A)\right]_i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the product rule
$$\begin{align}\partial_i\left (x_jA_j  \right )-\partial_j\left (x_jA_i  \right )+2A_i &= (x_j\partial_iA_j+A_j\partial_ix_j)-(x_j\partial_jA_i+A_i\partial_jx_j)+2A_i \\ 
&= (x_j\partial_iA_j+A_j\delta_{ij})-(x_j\partial_jA_i+A_i(3))+2A_i \\
&= x_j\partial_iA_j+A_i-x_j\partial_jA_i-3A_i+2A_i \\ 
&= x_j\partial_iA_j -x_j\partial_jA_i\end{align}$$ which is exactly what you have.

Note that, as a basic proof strategy, sometimes when verifying a theorem you'll want to work forward *and* backwards and then meet in the middle.